# How to clear unmanaged object memory in winform c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need clear unmanaged object memory in c# for example i would be open child form from main form perform some business logic after close the child form at all,that time need to be clear object memory

Comment: Please explain your problem with details on what you are trying to do, What effort you have put. And some piece of code.

Comment: This is what the `Dispose` method is for.  Make sure you call it !

Comment: In your description of this *process*, there's no mention of the *unmanaged objects* you're using.

Comment: Actually i have use windows application ,my application getting slow down while running ,app exe size would be increase every new window open at all

Comment: It sounds like you *may* have a *memory leak*. You don't resolve that by "clear unmanaged memory". You fix it by using a profiler to *locate the leak and fix it*.

Comment: This often happens because you're loading Bitmaps from a file or the project resources. In any case, assign a disposable object to a Field or local varial and `Dispose()` of it when you're done with that object. A wise use of `GC.Collect()` can help.

Answer (score 1):

When you closing Form, you should call `Dispose()` method, which will free used memory.

If you instantiating Form like
`Form1 form1 = new Form()`
`form1.Show()`
It is enought to call `form1.Close()` method which will call `Dispose()` itself.

But when you instantiating form like modal form `form1.ShowDialog()` you must call `form1.Dispose()` by yourself.

Explicit call of Garbage collector is very risky.